# how can I take one methods result as another methods' parameter

Tags: java, methods, call

I need to take this "over" statement under the overallmethod as finalmethods' parameter, how can I do this. I want to learn the final letter but to do that I want to access over statement.

```
public static void overallmethod(int quiz1,int quiz2,int quiz3,int     midterm,int grade){
          double quizzes = ( ((quiz1*10) + (quiz2*10) + (quiz3*10)) *25) /300;
          double finalg = ( grade * 40) / 100;
          double mid = (midterm * 35) / 100;
          double over = quizzes + finalg + mid;
          System.out.println("Your overall score is: " + over);
      }


        public static void finalmethod(double over){


        if(over <= 100 && over >= 90){

            System.out.println("Your final letter is: A");
        }
        else if(over >= 80) {
            System.out.println("Your final letter is: B");
        }
        else if (over >= 70) {
            System.out.println("Your final letter is: C");
        }
        else if (over >= 60) {
            System.out.println("Your final letter is: D");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your final letter is: F");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`over` is not a statement, it is a local variable now. Just make it class attribute:

`public static double over`

Comment: Yes I made it :D

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to return the variable `over` and change your return type to `double`.

```
public static double overallmethod(int quiz1,int quiz2,int quiz3,int midterm,int grade)
{          
    //Your code
    return over;
}
```

Then simply pass the value returned from the `overallmethod` to `finalmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your overall function return the value of over. Then just call the overall function inside the parameter list of finalmethod

Comment: but I have to use void so is it possible to do with void ?

Comment: @Ekin no it's not

Comment: If you need to use void, use tamas's answer

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to declare over as a private int outside both the methods, i.e. it should have visibility to all the methods in that class (class variable).

Now compute the overall score in the overallMethod and store it to the over variable.

Next, make a public method getOver() which returns the value of over, and call finalMethod in this way : ClassName.finalMethod(objectOfClass.getOver())

Answer (score 0):

By changing the return type of your method to double, and then passing the value in that method to the final method.